# Does a standalone neutron have temperature?

Tags: particle-physics, temperature, thermal-radiation, neutrons

Most objects exhibit a property called temperature which measures how much thermal energy is radiated off, and I think the electron(s) inside the atom or molecule is responsible for creating that light. So what happens if that object is an isolated neutron does it have temperature if it doesn't radiate energy? I can't speak calculus and it been quite a while so my algebra is a bit rusty I think you get the drift...

Comment: The question has no meaning. Temperature is defined as a measure of orderly motion of particles. It is a statistical measure. You need a lot of neutrons.

Comment: @YashasSamaga The question itself is meaningful (and the one-word answer is "no" as explained in the duplicate question) but the OP's ideas about the physics underlying the question seem rather confused.

Comment: Yeah. The question is meaningful with an answer "No". Sorry about that.